# Bot works on one Microsoft Teams Account but not on the other

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I have 2 different Microsoft Teams Accounts that are not linked in any way.

On one account I was able to sideload my bot and if I chat with my Bot in an Teams Channel my bot does Answer. Also it answeres me if I private message it.

On the other account I also sideloaded my bot but my Bot does not react if I message him in an Teams Channel. But it answeres me if I private message it.

I created both bots via App Studio in Teams.

Now I've noticed a difference in App Studio and I think this is why my Bot does not react.

Image of App Studio where the Bot works:

[image]

Image of App Studio where the Bot does not work:

[image]

The settings in App Studio where the Bot does not work are a bit shorter.

What is happening here? How can I make my Bot work?

Comment: Could you please confirm if the below answers solve your queries? Please let us know if you are still facing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colby's answer might be the fix to you problem, however there are also other permissions settings that you can consider as well, if that doesn't fix it.

---

> I have 2 different Microsoft Teams Accounts that are not linked in any way.

If your accounts are in different organizations, then it's possible that the lack of ability to see your bot that you've added in a Team Channel is due to settings set up by your org's admin. It states here in the [Admin settings for apps in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/admin-settings) article in the `Important` text block:

> Be sure you've turned on apps for Teams in [Tenant-wide settings in the Microsoft 365 admin center.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365#tenant-wide-settings-in-the-microsoft-365-admin-center) If you want to add external apps (provided by third parties), you'll need to turn on [External apps settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365#external-apps).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see I think your issue is because the scope on your other bot is set to only Personal. If you click on edit and select "Team" via the Scope section it should fix your issue. Let me know if that helped.

[image: Bot Scope]